# How to store an authentication token client-side?

Tags: encryption, https, password-protection, bearer-token

## Goal

As a client application i want to store my session-token i received from the Server after a successful authentication so next time i dont have to be bothered again with authentication.

Should i take extra measures protecting my server from compromised clients if i store these access tokens in plain text in the clients?

## Additional Context

- Server runs over a TLS connection
- these session tokens are valid for a limited amount of time (1 day)
- authentication and authorization requests are rate-limited.

Alternatively, my idea was to expose an API on the server side that can sign the session-key and give it back again. I would store this signed key on the disk. Next time the client could ask the server first to un-encrypt my signed key so i have my session-key back. instead of authenticating again.

Comment: Signed tokens are fairly standard, see [JWT](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: `Should i take extra measures protecting my server from compromised clients` How would you know the client is compromised? Usually it's the client's task to protect the token. OS must authenticate the user to log-in, browsers should encrypt their cookie storage, etc.  Some sites (e.g. banks) are enforcing strict rules (e.g. client IP address for session, ...), but it may cause additional issues (e.g. with mobile internet)

Comment: In this case, Im the one building the client application (as well as the server side), which is a dedicated desktop application. @PresidentJamesK.Polk I might go for a JWT implementation, but token size is a bit of a concern to me

Comment: `Im the one building the client application (as well as the server side), which is a dedicated desktop application` when storing data safely, you may try to consider using the TPM (Trusted Platform Module) to encrypt the stored token (or rather - encrypt an envelope key to encrypt the access token). How to access it depends on the platform and language used.